# Applying for MS in USA after completing 3 years degree in India

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

I have completed my Bachelor of Computer Applications (BCA) from India. The minimum requirement for admission into the MS in Computer Science program requires a 4 year college degree. My BCA degree was a 3 year degree and I am planning on pursuing a 1 year Post Graduate Diploma in Computer Applications (PGDCA) from Indira Gandhi National Open University (IGNOU) and would like to find out if these total 4 years satisfy as minimum requirements for admission consideration.

Comment: You're welcome, Nikita. @jakebeal: Done.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to inquire such information at one or, better, more international academic credential evaluation companies, such as [WES](http://wes.org) (be careful, as I've had some negative experience with them in terms of accuracy of evaluation). Nevertheless, you can check the WES' [international-to-US academic credential equivalency tool](http://www.wes.org/evaluations/preliminary.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask a professor you know that has some connections with professors in US to tell you more about that.

Comment: i tried talking to every possible professor but none of them could get it confirmed. i also tried contacting the universities by mailing them my query but they said they cannot assure and the admission committee will decide when i apply