# How to obtain a degree equivalency certificate in UK?

Tags: degree, academic-life, united-kingdom, credentials

I have a degree in *Social Education* (done in Portugal). I am wondering whether anybody can help me in finding organizations that can provide an *equivalency certificate (report)* for this degree. I have searched and a degree in *Social Pedagogy* is very similar to mine. However, I don't know how to obtain an equivalency certificate (report) for that degree either.

Comment: Are you planning to use such a certificate to help in obtaining a professional license in another country?  What country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK, [NARIC](https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/) is the government designated agency for comparing foreign qualifications to their UK equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

There are various companies that offer commercial services of varied quality for generating and delivering *degree equivalency certificates (reports)* as well as some other related services. One of the most well-known such companies is *World Education Services (WES)* (in their terminology, an equivalency certificate and the process of its generation are referred to as a *credential evaluation*). Please see my [related answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/46852/12391) for a bit more details and a warning about WES.

I would suggest you to consider performing an Internet search for finding similar companies and comparing their services against your specific requirements before finalizing your decision.